# *EP pin connect to Ground

Tags: ground, packages

I was just wondering what is the function of the ***EP** pin on most **TQFN** package chips?

It says I should connect **EP** to **ground**, what happens if I don't ground it (I forgot)?

Comment: Are you referring to the "exposed pad" on the bottom of the chip?

Comment: Yes I was referring to the exposed pad on the bottom of the chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You talking about the pad on the underside of the part?  Most likely that's there to dissipate heat.  People like to put parts in smaller and smaller packages but the heat that the silicon generates needs to get out somewhere.  If it's just some digital IC and it has other GND pins it will most likely work.  Should be fine if you're just messing around or prototyping, but fix it before you make more.  Just watch the temperature of the thing.

If it's a mosfet or some other driver designed to dissipate heat then you may be in trouble.  You might be able to counter it by putting a little heat sink on top of it.   On the other hand if there's no other GND connection then you're in trouble.

Usually an IC is designed to operate in a range of temperatures so if you're just on the bench at 27C you have a good chance of being ok for now.

When you fix your board keep in mind that you probably don't want to just "connect" it to GND.  If you look in the back of the datasheet for it you'll probably see a recommended land pattern that shows how many vias it wants to GND and maybe even a requirement to have some copper fill connected to it on the back.

Comment: Yes that what I was talking about, thank you very much there are other ground pins and its not dissipating a lot of heat so I will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The pad on the bottom of most TQFN packages is to be connected to ground on your circuit board. **Do note that you should read the data sheet carefully** for your specific part to determine if this is meant to be connected to ground or not. There are some devices where there may be alternate recommendations from the manufacturer.

You should always follow the manufacturers directions regarding this pad and not try to guess what will happen if you choose to ignore this. In the past I have seen projects where the design engineer neglected to follow the manufacturer's directions for how to handle this pad and ended up with huge amounts of wasted debug time. This can be particularly problematic for some parts where the pad is connected to the chip in a way requires a good solid PCB connection to the correct thing.

A ground connection to this pad can be important for many devices because this pad is generally used to cool the device. Vias in the pad corners of the PCB footprint down into the GND plane will conduct heat away from the chip into the copper of the board.